# Is a secret token generated with /dev/urandom a good way to protect a daemon?

Tags: security, unix, posix

I have a daemon process which spawns subprocesses. Sometimes these subprocesses need to communicate back to the daemon. I want to ensure that only these subprocesses are authorized to communicate with the daemon.

I want to implement this as follows:

- During startup, the daemon generates a random 128-byte secret token by reading /dev/urandom. /dev/random is no good because it may block the reader for an arbitrary amount of time.
- The daemon listens on a Unix domain socket.
- The daemon puts the secret token and the filename of the socket in environment variables. Every subprocess that it spawns can connect to the daemon using the filename and the secret token.
- The daemon rejects the connection unless the secret token is correct.

Questions:

- I know that /dev/random has higher entropy than /dev/urandom. But is /dev/urandom good enough? If not, what should I use?
- Is the size of the token large enough?
- Should I lock the memory in which the token is stored? I don't think it's necessary because the daemon generates a different token every time it's started, so by the time an attacker manages to steal the hard drive and extract the token from the swap file, it should already be useless.
- Should I nullify the memory in which the token is stored during shutdown?
- Anything else I should do?

And because of various requirements, I cannot use anonymous pipes to allow communication between the daemon and subprocesses.

Comment: What kind of attack are you afraid of? "good enough" depends on the answer to that question. The size is IMO large enough to prevent brute-force attacks.

Comment: The daemon keeps a kind of in-memory database. I only want the subprocesses to be able to view and manipulate this in-memory database.

Comment: But is /dev/urandom a sufficiently secure source of entropy that a brute force attack is the only way to obtain the token? Attackers might have local non-root access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the security provided by /dev/urandom is plenty good enough. Lots of software uses it for randomness (for SSL, authentication, etc). Pretty much the only time /dev/random is a good idea is when generating some kind of a token that needs to be secure for years, such as a private key for a certificate.

Someone mentioned ability to look at process's memory if you have the same UID. You can avoid that by making kernel think it's a setuid-process, i.e. if the master process runs as root you can fork, exec and setuid() to unprivileged user. Other processes with same UID won't be able to look at that process's memory then.

The credentials lookup approach also works with named UNIX sockets, not just socketpairs.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach would be to simply create a pipe/socketpair in the server for each subprocess.  Give one end to the subprocess and keep the other end.  Anything that comes in on that pipe/socket must be from that subprocess.

Another approach would be to ask the OS for the credentials (pid, uid, gid) from the Unix socket.  On Linux you would use `getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PEERCRED, &cr, &cr_len)` (`man 7 socket`).  Solaris has `getpeerucred`.  Unfortunately this is not portable but many systems have a similar capability for Unix sockets.  Although it is complex, [D-Bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus) contains [code that does this on a number of different systems](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/dbus/dbus/tree/dbus/dbus-sysdeps-unix.c?id=dbus-1.2.14#n1120).

Comment: He said he couldn't use pipes; don't know if that extends to socketpair.  +1 on credentials.  They haven't entered my mind in a dog's age.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you're going to put the token into an environment variable then anyone with the same or greater privileges (i.e. UID) as those processes will be able to read then use the token! That kinda makes the rest of the question a moot point!? If you are worried about security between processes on the same box (you spoke of local IPC) then don't use an environment variable to store a token - it is easy to inspect these (EVs).

Comment: You mean that external processes can inspect any process's environment variables as long as they have the same UID? Okay, in that case I can pass the token through a temporary pipe and have it stored in the subprocess's memory.

Comment: And of course if you have sufficient rights, you can inspect the memory of other processes as well. I'm afraid that you're going to realize that security through obscurity is not a roadblock, it's a speedbump. There is no way you can protect this 100%, but you can make it harder.

Comment: If the attacker has sufficient rights to inspect environment variables or memory, you've already lost.

Comment: Suppose that the attacker has local non-root access, but no access to the account under which the daemon and the subproceses are running. Would my scheme be secure enough?

Answer (score 1):

If you're forking (but not exec()ing), just keeping them in local memory should be enough. If you're also exec()ing, you'll probably (as you stated in your comment to Jim) have to pass the token (and domain socket path) over a pipe.

If you're running this on head-less servers, /dev/random MAY be a bit starved, so using /dev/urandom will (probably) be a better option, unless you have a suitable source of noise to feed /dev/random with.